# Grammatical Structure of Complex Sentence

Tags: phrasal-verbs, modal-verbs, subordinate-clauses, complex-sentences, subordinators

**The Sentence in Question**

> The legal “theories” of democracy that evolved in the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries were precisely intended to provide such definitions as would link certain actual or ideal forms of government to the ideology of the Rule by the People
> --(Capitalism, Socialism and Democracy, Schumpeter).

**My question**

I understand the overall gist of the sentence, but I can't for the life of me figure out its grammatical structure. Sure, it’s a complex sentence: main clause up until “definitions,” subordinate from “as.” What confuses me is (what I can’t help but assume to be) the subordinating conjunction, because I’ve never seen “as would” used that way. I’d greatly appreciate if someone could break the sentence down word by word, even if only the subordinate clause, especially if there are words which were implied to avoid verbosity.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's an odd use of the  _such/so ... that_ idiom. The phrase is _provide such definitions as would link certain..._ The use of _as_ is in place of _that_ as a consequence of the phrase _such as_.  The whole thing means "such definitions that would link certain..."

Comment: @JohnLawler: It seems to me the whole thing just means *"[provide] **definitions that would** link certain..."*. In which context ***such*** is completely optional - and whether it's present or not, it doesn't seem to convey anything meaningfully different to ***the, those, any, some*** (or even ***a selection of*** ).

Comment: Replace "definitions *as* would"  with "definitions **of the kind that** would."

Comment: *such...as* means *those...that*: *The theories were intended to provide **those** definitions **that** would link certain forms of government...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Such ... as* means *those ... that*:

Before:
*The theories were intended to provide **such** definitions **as** would link certain forms of government...*

After:
*The theories were intended to provide **those** definitions **that** would link certain forms of government...*

So *such* functions as a determiner like *those*, and *as* functions as a relative pronoun like *that*.

> **such**, *adj.* and *pron.*
>
> Signification.
>
> *Such* is a demonstrative word used to indicate the quality or quantity of a thing by reference to that of another or with respect to
> the effect that it produces or is capable of producing. Thus,
> syntactically, *such* may have backward or forward reference; in the
> uses of branch I it has the former, in those of branch II mainly the
> latter.
>
> **II.** Where the meaning is determined by reference to a correlative or subordinate clause
> **11.** ***such..as*** (Old English *swá*): the..that, *plural* those..that; any or all..that; as many (or as much)..as.
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Below are selected samples from the OED entry; swap in *the*, *those*, *any*, *all*, or *most* — as applicable — for *such*, and swap in *that* for *as*:

> <sub>1545   R. TAVERNER tr. Erasmus *Prouerbes* (new ed.) sig. Gv
>   Such ale as he hath brewed, let hi drinke him self.</sub>
>
> <sub>1835   J. DUNCAN *Nat. Hist. Beetles* (Naturalist’s Libr.:
> Entomol. II) 182   This genus..comprehends such insects as have
> the antennæ slightly compressed.</sub>
>
> <sub>1737   *Gentleman’s Mag.* May 261/2   These, being such
> as occur to my Memory at present.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this use of "as" treated variously, but I like [Merriam-Webster's interpretation of it as a (relative) pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as):

> : THAT, WHO, WHICH —used after *same* or *such*
> // in the same building *as* my brother
> // … tears such *as* angels weep …
> — John Milton
> and chiefly dialect after a substantive not modified by *same* or *such*
> // … that kind of fruit *as* maids call medlars …
> — William Shakespeare

(I don't understand how the first example is relevant, but the quotations from Milton and Shakespeare nicely illustrate this use of "as".)

In this case, "as" functions as the subject of the relative clause.